# Google Map Javascript Api through ASp.net mvc or core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Some one plz guide me I am making project vehicle tracking and use google map Now I am stuck here how can I get the multiple latitude longitude by click event  and save into the database Because I want to create a geo fence. Someone plz help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Api is not free .For tracking each longitude and latitude on every single refresh will cost you money.